# NFC P2P as3911 <--> phone

Tags: android, c, blackberry, nfc

In my project I try to connect as3911 with phone by P2P mode. I use libraries of Oliver Regenfelder.

After initialization as3911 in target mode, I'm waiting for message from phone (blackberry or phone with android). When phone touches as3911 I reseive atr_request:

adroid: 1E D4 00 A1 84 17 06 67 2E 76 8D B2 79 00 00 00 32 46 66 6D 01 01 11 03 02 00 13 04 01 96
blackberry: 06 00 FF FF 00 03

Afterwards I send my atr_response:
0x1F, 0xD5, 0x01,
0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x32,
0x46, 0x66, 0x6D,
0x01, 0x01, 0x11, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x13, 0x04, 0x01, 0x96

I don't reseive response form phone (initiator).
I'm not interested in upper layers of protocol, but why I don't receive response?

as3911 work good with nfc cards, so I can suppose that isn't a problem with initialization.

Answer (score 0):

do not put 0x1F(package length) in atr_response buffer, the package length was auto process by lib.

Note: Refer to AS3911 Datasheet -> "Application Information" -> "NFCIP-1 Operation" -> "Transmission" section.